# PhantomJSDriver Accept Alert

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

How can I accept an alert with PhantomJSDriver in Java? I am trying to do this with YouTube. I can't get it to work.

I've tried using this code to accept on any driver but it doesn't work with PhantomJS.

```
static void confirmDialog(WebDriver driver) {
    if (driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
        PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
        phantom.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
        phantom.executeScript("return window.confirm");
    } else driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must execute JS to set the window.alert call to do nothing. You can use this method.

```
static void confirmDialog(WebDriver driver) {
    if (driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
        PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
        phantom.executeScript("window.alert = function(){}");
        phantom.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
    } else driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavascriptExecutor worked for me. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box.
Above code by default set the confirmation box as `true` means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked

Hope it will help you :)