# Unable to handle alert using phantomJS in Java

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have a Java code as below and when I am running through PhantomJs getting "Unsupported Command Exception" but it is working fine if I run through firefox and chrome:-

Note: With phantomJs we could able to execute till 3rd step in below code.I searched in many blogs but those answers didn't solve my problem.

```
1.      cvvField.sendKeys(cvcData);
2.      proceedToPayBtn.click();
3.      Reporter.log("Card details are submitted from payment UI page");
4.      Alert a1=driver.switchTo().alert();
5.      Reporter.log("Alert with text:"+a1.getText());
6.      a1.accept();
```

Here cvvField and proceedToPayBtn are WebElements and cvcData have value as "111".

Error log:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Invalid Command Method - 

{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Host":"localhost:30462","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_101)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/alert_text","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"alert_text","directory":"/","path":"/alert_text","relative":"

/alert_text","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/alert_text","queryKey":{},"chunks":["alert_text"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/9e392a50-ce79-11e6-b24a-2b12cf1ec4d6/alert_text"}
```

Command duration or timeout: `31 milliseconds`

> I have edited above code as below but same error is coming.Please suggest

```
 if (driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver)
       {
         JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
         je.executeScript("window.alert = function(){};");
         je.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;};");    
         System.out.println("Alert has been handled");
       } else {
             Alert a1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
             a1.accept();
       }
```

> I am getting "Alert has been handled" in output console but alert is not handled.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit amble

Comment: I have edited above code as below but still its not working,Showing same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994845/phantomjsdriver-accept-alert/53439230#53439230 has a solution which worked for me

Comment: This solution @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994845/phantomjsdriver-accept-alert/53439230#53439230 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Some issue due to wait time can be the source of your problem
The code above can help to wait until element is visible (since the wait of ngWebDriver or Selenium Webdriver are not compatible with PhantomJS)

```
public static String waitJSResponse(PhantomJSDriver driver, String script) {
        String ReturnedValue = null;
        int sleeper = 10;
        Boolean flag = false;
        int timeOut = 30000;
        int i = 0;
        while ((!flag) & ((i*sleeper)<timeOut)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleeper);
                ReturnedValue = (String) driver.executeScript(script);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
                i++;
            }
            if (ReturnedValue != null) {
                flag = true;
                System.out.println("Overall wait time is : "+(i * sleeper)+" ms \n\r");
                break;
            }
        }
        return ReturnedValue;
    }
```

This code will wait 10ms then verify that the element is visble, if there is an exception, it will loop again.
The returned value must be a text, an object or anything that is not null.
the script value must be your JS script to get the correct element.

Hope it work.

I tried the above code by:-

1.Creating a class "Test" and writing above method in it.
2.Above method is called by creating an object(TestObject) as

> TestObject.waitJSResponse((PhantomJSDriver) driver, "window.confirm = function(){return true;};");

But ReturnedValue in

`try`
    `{`
`Thread.sleep(sleeper);`
`ReturnedValue = (String) driver.executeScript(script);`
`System.out.println(ReturnedValue);`

`}`

returns null.So Can u please help with this?

Comment: I responded with my feedback. Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You don't need to do a Thread.sleep(sleeper), just add the waitJSResponse as a function then put the script you want into the parameters, tried it for my code and it worked

Comment: Thanks @Hamza Amami. Can you please help me  with this also    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503733/pop-up-handling-through-phantomjs-in-java

Comment: Welcome, I'll try

Comment: I am not able to accept alert. its still returning the null value after removing Thread.sleepe(sleeper).

Comment: I again tried with your above code but it falls in continuous loop. How to handle without adding break inside try block?