# Pop up handling through PhantomJs in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

> Hi, I have a html page as below and i need to handle pop up generated in it in phantomjs using java code.Please provide the solution code.

```
<html> 
<body> 

Card Number: 
<br> 
<input type="text" name="Card Number" value=""> 
<br> 
Card Holder Name: 
<br> 
<input type="text" name="Card Holder Name" value=""> 
<br><br> 
CVV: 
<br> 
<input type="text" name="CVV" value=""> 
<br> 
<br> 
<input type="button" value="proceed" onclick="myFunction()"> 

<script> 
function myFunction() { 
var x; 
if (confirm("Would you like to proceed payment!") == true) { 
x = "You pressed OK!"; 
} else { 
x = "You pressed Cancel!"; 
} 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
} 
</script> 



</body> 
</html>
```

> I tried with [Unable to handle alert using phantomJS in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394645/unable-to-handle-alert-using-phantomjs-in-java/]) and Github https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/500 but it is not fruitful.

Comment: Is it a popup or alert ??

Comment: and yeah, is it an AngularJS based website ?

Comment: It is an Alert  and website is MVC based in which jquery is used.

Comment: Have you tried window switch ?

Comment: Maybe that's a modal window? I think  that's not a `pop-up / alert() / prompt()`

Comment: Right click is disabled on Alert. Also,I am not able to identify any element on it using any means.Meanwhile I tried with window handling method but same result i am getting.